# Current SpringBoot OAuth2 approach

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I spent 2 days of going through various Tutorials for a SpringBoot OAuth2 Client.
And every looked slightly different.
Furthermore none of them worked since several Classes were not found the the given Packages.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webclient-oauth2

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-oauth2-login#setup

https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/06/using-spring-security-5-to-integrate-with-oauth-2-secured-services-such-as-facebook-and-github

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide
...

Probably I confused myself meanwhile. But I could really use a working example or documentation on how to implement OAuth2 Client correctly in SpringBoot this month.

I would appreciate any helping link or just an example (with POM versions) to achieve that.

Thanks in advance

Gregor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope This blogs will help you

https://www.devglan.com/spring-security/spring-security-oauth2-user-registration
https://waynestalk.com/en/spring-security-oauth2-google-signin-explained-en/

this are the blogs that explains clearly

Answer (score 1):

You need to do four simple things:

**Step 1: Create Facebook App ID**

First of all, you need to create Facebook developer account and create a Facebook App for OAuth authentication.

Then obtain the App ID and App Secret of your new Facebook App, to be used in the project configuration. And note that for testing on localhost you don't need to specify a redirect URI.

**Step 2: Add Spring Boot OAuth2 Client Dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Step 3: Configure Spring OAuth2 Properties for Facebook**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: spring-oauth2-security-example
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: <client-id>
      clientSecret: <clientSecret>
      accessTokenUri: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
      tokenName: oauth_token
      authenticationScheme: query
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com/me
```

This is Facebook specific setting, what you only need to provide is the clientID (or App ID) and clientSecret or your App secret key. Both of this can be found on Facebook Developer page when you created the app.

**Step 4: Update main class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SpringOauth2SecurityExampleApplication {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String welcome(Principal principal) {
        Map<String, Object> details = (Map<String, Object>)
                ((OAuth2Authentication) principal).getUserAuthentication().getDetails();
        String userName = (String) details.get("name");
        return "Hi " + userName + " Welcome to my application !!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringOauth2SecurityExampleApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**NB:** It should be noted that you need to add your endpoint url that you'll use for authentication to the "valid oAuth redirected url" setting on Facebook. Because the oAuth will only work for a specific address. In this case, we're running this locally so I'm going to put `localhost:8080` and `localhost:8080/login`

[image]

**Step 5: Test**

Go to `localhost:8080`, it will automatically redirected to OAuth because everything on your site is restricted for access and you must be authenticated first.

[image]

**Hope this will help you!**